# Access Ruby 'self' methods inside 'class << self' method definitions

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, class-method

While watching [this video](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/metaprogramming-ruby) I came across an interesting question posed by the presenter, Dave Thomas. He is talking about the syntax we see all the time in Ruby class method definitions:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    def bar
      puts "inside class method"
    end
    def self.baz
      puts "inside anonymous superclass method"
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, we can access `Foo.bar`, but how does one go about `baz`? Dave Thomas talks about the `class << self` syntax inserting an anonymous superclass into the hierarchy. I tried the following:

- Calling `Foo.superclass.baz`doesn't work because `Foo.superclass` is just `Object`.
- I poked around the available methods of the ancestry hierarchy to no avail.
- `Test.class_eval 'self.self.baz'`...now things are getting a little ridiculous.

Thoughts?

The problem is presented around 44:23 in the video.

Comment: At the end of the video, Dave explains several ways to do it, each more elegant than the last.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the video, we are offered several answers to this question.

First, something pretty ugly. You can reopen the class:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    baz
  end
end
```

And another way. Since class definitions are executed, you can return the inner `self` into a variable:

```
meta = class Foo
  class << self
    def self.baz
      puts "inside anonymous superclass method"
    end
    self # return self here
  end
end

meta.baz
```

Or, most elegantly you can open `Class` and add a method to it:

```
class Class
  def meta
    class << self
      self
    end
  end
end

# class Foo ...

Foo.meta.baz
```

which turns out to be just a reimplementation of `Object#singleton_class`.

Comment: Your `Class#meta` is just a re-implementation of `Object#singleton_class`.